# Cannot get an array from a selected option in a dropdown menu (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

When I select an option in my dropdown menu, I expect it to show the value of it. The problem is that the values of each available option are lists of values from Flask. Ex.: '{{ column1 }}' has the value - without double-quotes - "['abc', 'def', 'ghi']". So, when I select an option, it only returns the first item of the list. Ex. (without double-quotes): "['abc',".

Is there any workaround for returning the full list of values?

```
<script>
    function showOptions(s) {
    alert(s[s.selectedIndex].value);
    alert(s[s.selectedIndex].id);
    }
</script>

<select  onchange="showOptions(this)" id="my_select2">
    <option value={{ column1 }} id={{ column1 }}>{{ label_a1 }}</option>
    <option value={{ column2 }} id={{ column2 }}>{{ label_b1 }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why you have tagged python in your question?

Comment: Please show the final HTML, not the template source. And remove unrelated tags (python, flask). My guess is that your HTML looks like this: `value=['abc', 'def', 'ghi']`; it's invalid, but browsers are lenient and it's parsed as `value="['abc',"`

Comment: I have tagged Python because as said before, my values come from Flask.

Comment: It doesn't matter where they come from. All that matters is a) how does the final HTML look like, the code that is sent to the browser b) what does the JS code do to it. Everything else is noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change each `value={{ column1 }} id={{ column1 }}` wrapping doubles quotes around `{{ ... }}`

From

```
value={{ column1 }} id={{ column1 }}
```

To

```
value="{{ column1 }}" id="{{ column1 }}"
```

Otherwise, your value will be something that is exactly like this : `value=['abc', 'def', 'ghi']`, this means that `value=['abc',` (the space ends the value assigned, because there is no double quotes to delimit them)

On other words, from

```js
function showOptions(s) {
    alert(s[s.selectedIndex].value);
    alert(s[s.selectedIndex].id);
    }
```

```html
<select  onchange="showOptions(this)" id="my_select2">
    <option value=['abc', 'def', 'ghi'] id=['abc', 'def', 'ghi']>{{ label_a1 }}</option>
<!--        ^-----------^------ This is your value attribute  -->
    <option value=['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr'] id=['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr']>{{ label_b1 }}</option>
</select>
```

To

```js
function showOptions(s) {
    alert(s[s.selectedIndex].value);
    alert(s[s.selectedIndex].id);
    }
```

```html
<select  onchange="showOptions(this)" id="my_select2">
    <option value="['abc', 'def', 'ghi']" id="['abc', 'def', 'ghi']">{{ label_a1 }}</option>
<!--        ^---------------------------^------ This is the value attribute you want -->
    <option value="['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr']" id="['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr']">{{ label_b1 }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Perfect, Cid! Solve the issue quickly and easily! Thanks.